# Shiny and conditional statements

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny server.R which is trying to do the following:

I have a selectInput on the sidebar which allows the user to choose one of 2 conditions, which subsequently changes the UI, which is made up of conditional panels, one for each condition.

My server.R is set up in the following way:

```
if (input$option1) {return()}
else{run code corresponding to option 2 which outputs reactive variable 2}

if (input$option2) {return()}
else{run code corresponding to option 1 which outputs reactive variable 1}
.
.
.
run another function that depends on variable 1 or variable 2, depending on which input is chosen above
```

The reason the above code does not work is because in order to refer to input$option*, I need to be in a reactive environment.  But clearly, I can't put it in an isolate() call, because I need the UI to respond to the user input. And clearly I can't put it in an observe() call, because I need to be able to output variable 1 or variable 2 depending on the conditional logic.  So how do I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish? I can provide my code if necessary, but I think this is more of a design/program flow issue.

Thanks. Code is below:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    headerPanel("App"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "simtype",
        "Select Simulation Type",
        c(SingleSubject = "SS", FromFile = "FF"),
        selected = "FF",
        multiple = FALSE
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.simtype=='FF' ",
        fileInput(
          'file1',
          'Upload File Here',
          accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')
        ),
        #    tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons(
          'sep',
          'Separator',
          c(
            Comma = ',',
            Semicolon = ';',
            Tab = '\t'
          ),
          'Comma'
        ),
        uiOutput('varselect1')
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.simtype== 'SS' ",
        aceEditor(
          "text",
          "",
          mode = "r",
          theme = "twilight",
          height = "40px",
          fontSize = 10
        ),
        uiOutput('varselect2')
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(#uiOutput('tabs')
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title = 'FILE', value = "filetab", tableOutput("filetable")),
        tabPanel(
          title = "SUMMARY",
          value = "summarytab",
          dataTableOutput("summarytable")
        ),
        id = "tabs"
      ))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    if (input$simtype == "SS") {
      return()
    }  else{
      file <- reactive({
        file <- input$file1
      })
      output$filetable <- renderTable({
        file()
      })

    } #end if
    output$varselect1 <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$file1$datapath)) {
        return()
      }

      list(actionButton("goButton", 'GO'),
           numericInput("s1", "Input value 1", NULL))

    }) # end renderUI()

    if (input$simtype == "FF") {
      return()
    } else{
      get.text <- reactive({
        input$text
      })
      output$filetable <- renderTable({
        X <- read.table(text = get.text())
        X
      }) # end renderTable()

    } #end if
    output$varselect2 <- renderUI({
      if (input$text == "") {
        return()
      }

      list(numericInput("s0", "Input value", NULL),
           actionButton("goButton", 'GO'))

    })
    #end renderUI()
    mydata <- reactive({
      input$goButton
      if (input$simtype == "FF") {
        variable = file()
      } else {
        variable = X()
      }
    }) #end mydata()
    output$summarytable <- renderDataTable({
      variable
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: It's very unclear exactly where you have this code or what you expect it to do. It would be nice if you could create a minimal reproducible example that can can run to see exactly what you are doing and test possible solutions/alternatives. (Ideally a call to `runApp` with a list for the `ui=` and `server=` functions like at the bottom of the `?runApp` help page.)

Comment: There seem to be plenty of syntax errors if I try to copy/paste that into R so it is not runnable. Also you have a problem with your `if/else` syntax. If your if statement executes a block (`{..}`), the `else` but start on the same line as the closing `}`. It cannot start on a new line. Otherwise it can be ambiguous as to where the else belongs.

Comment: Try it now.  It should run, except it runs into the issue mentioned in the original question, i.e., I cannot call input$* without being in a reactive context.

Comment: Nope. Still get errors. First error is `unexpected 'else'`. it looks like you made no attempt to fix your `if/else` problem i mentioned.

Comment: it runs now.  The problem you are mentioning is a stylistic issue.

Comment: at least, I think it is...am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. i'm telling you, [you are wrong](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#if). Also, what library does `aceEditor` come from?

Comment: shinyAce. Hmm, maybe what youre mentioning is the source of my issues....

Comment: Do you see the issue, now?  In my if statement where I check for input$simtype, it won't evaluate unless I am ina reactive environment.  But I can't put input$simtype in an isolate() since I need the UI to change based on input$simtype.  And I dont know how to use observe() here, if I even should at all.

Comment: can't you just have two reactive environments, one triggered by the `TRUE` if condition, and one triggered by the `FALSE` if condition?

Comment: The issue is how to call the if conditions....

Comment: Does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556612/rendering-shiny-user-inputs-based-on-conditional-logic-in-server

Comment: sort of. But remember, I have to RETURN a variable from the code after the if statement, so I can't use observe().  Observe doesn't return anything. This is my issue.

Comment: or are you saying wrap EVEYRHTING in one giant observe()?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very hard time understanding what you were trying to do. I've tried to move the code around and reformat to see if that helps. I really didn't have any idea what data you were feeding into the programs so I didn't have a good way to test.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    headerPanel("App"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("simtype", "Select Simulation Type", list(SingleSubject="SS", FromFile="FF" ),  selected="SS", multiple=FALSE),

      conditionalPanel(condition="input.simtype=='FF' ",
        fileInput('file1', 'Upload File Here', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t'),',') #change 'Comma' to ','

      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.simtype== 'SS' ",
        aceEditor("text", "", mode="r", theme="twilight", height="40px",fontSize = 10 )
      ),
      uiOutput('varselect')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(title='FILE', value="filetab", tableOutput("filetable")),
        tabPanel(title="SUMMARY", value="summarytab", dataTableOutput("summarytable")),
      id="tabs") 
    )
   ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    userdata <- reactive({  
      x<-if(input$simtype=="SS" && input$text != "") {
        read.table(text=input$text)
      } else if (input$simtype=="FF" && !is.null(input$file1$datapath)) {
        read.table(input$file1$datapath)
      } else {
        data.frame()
      }
      x
    })

    output$varselect <- renderUI({
      if(nrow(userdata())>0){list()} 
      list(
        numericInput("s1", "Input value 1", NULL),
        actionButton("goButton",'GO')
      )
    }) # end renderUI()

    currentdata <- reactive({
      input$goButton        
      isolate(userdata())
    })

    output$filetable <- renderTable({
      currentdata()
    })

    output$summarytable<- renderDataTable({
      currentdata()
    })

  } #end server
))
```

Comment: I tried to be clear above. I have two reactive panels that change based on user input.  If user inputs choice A, one panel appears, and they enter data.  If user inputs choice B, the other pane appaears, and they enter data.  That data is then passed to another function, regardless of which option was chosen.  But how that data looks DEPENDS on what option was chosen.  In the first case, the data comes from a file.  In the second case, the data is entered MANUALLY by the user.  I'm just trying to get it so that, regardless of how the data is entered, the program can analyze it.

Comment: So did my sample accomplish that or did I miss something?

Comment: I've edited my code based on Alex's suggestion above. I still can't get it to work but I am getting closer, I think

Comment: I just pasted into a clean R session and it ran. Did you get an error or something?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it ran. And i appreciate your help.  But the logic is slightly different than what I am trying to do. Lemme look at yours more deeply.